# Error in A %*% B : non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

```
A = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), byrow = T, ncol = 3)
B = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),ncol = 3)
A%*%B
```

could anyone explain why it shows error?

Answer (score 0):

We could transpose one of them

```
tcrossprod(A, B)
```

or

```
A %*% t(B)
```

---

It is just that the row of one `matrix` and the column length of other should be same